# How do i create a blocking system with mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've created a little social website which has three simple tables as show below.

```
Table User
id (pk)  | user_name
1       | a
2       | b
3       | c

Table Post
id (pk)  | user_id (fk)
1       | 1
2       | 3
3       | 2
4       | 2

Table Block
id (pk) | block_by (fk)  | blocked_to (fk)
1       | 1              | 2
```

The user can block anyone they want, and if blocking happen, two users will not longer see each other posts on their newfeeds.
From my table that mean `user1` and `user2` will not see each other posts but 'user3' will normally see everyone' post because he not belong to the table block.

```
    select * from Post p 
where p.user_id not in 
(select b.blocked_to from Block b  
where b.block_by = '$_SESSION[userid]')
```

From SQL query user1 cannot see user2's post, **but user2 still see user1 post,** this is i don't want. What is the best query for this situation that i can do?
Please also consider my database design is this good way to go? You can suggest me, Many thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try joining the `Post` and `Block` tables in order to filter out posts requested by a given user (which you obtain through the session) belonging to other potentially blocked users:

```
SELECT * FROM Post p INNER JOIN Block b
ON p.user_id = b.blocked_by
WHERE b.blocked_to <> '$_SESSION[userid]'
```

I would also modify your schema slightly to include *both* relationships in the `Block` table:

```
+---------+---------------+-----------------+
| id (pk) | block_by (fk) | blocked_to (fk) |
+---------+---------------+-----------------+
|   1     |      1        |       2         |
|   2     |      2        |       1         |
+---------+---------------+-----------------+
```

First of all, I believe this is the easiest way to represent a two-way relationship.  At worst, the `Block` table would double in size.  Furthermore, you don't know if at some point in the future you might have a scenario where a block is one way.  For example, you might allow User 1 to block User 2, where User 1 can still read User 2 posts but not vice versa.

Comment: If user 1 block user2, user2 should still be able to block user 1. You can't save two relationships when there is only one

Comment: Who said there is only one relationship?  My design allows for _both_ relationships to exist, or just one.

Comment: what if user has no record on blocks table?

Answer (score 5):

You have to check `block_by` and `block_to` fields.

```
SELECT * FROM Post p 
WHERE p.user_id NOT IN (
    SELECT b.blocked_to AS userId FROM Block b  
    WHERE b.block_by = {$_SESSION['userid']}
    UNION DISTINCT 
    SELECT b.blocked_by AS userId FROM Block b  
    WHERE b.block_from = {$_SESSION['userid']}
)
```

You should also use quotes when accessing fields in your `$_SESSION` array (`$_SESSION['userid']` instead of `$_SESSION[userid]`).

Comment: I've tried and that doesn't work, user2 still see user1's posts. I think i may create two relations either 1 block 2 and 2 block 1 that only the solution i can figured out right now.

Comment: @Marcus I've updated my answer. Could you please try it again?

Comment: Yes, it worked thanks @mapek and everyone for answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - I haven't thought this through fully, but I think you can use a join to the Block table on conditions where your user is not in either of the Block columns. However I think that would mean each Post would join to every qualifying row in the Block table - hence adding the 'distinct' to avoid duplicates. Whether the optimizer can handle that without doing a massive table scan I am not sure, but here's the idea, up for discussion.

```
select distinct post.id from Post
left outer join Block on block_by <> $_SESSION['userid']
 and blocked_to <> $_SESSION['userid'];
```