# What Sql Join can I use to combine my three tables

Tags: php, mysql

I made a query that user can see all the post of active users but not of those inactive, but also they should not see the post of users they blocked or blocked them how can I do that?, the block_users table has block_by_userid and blocked_userid column.

I tried INNER JOIN the post table with members table which every inactive users post cannot be seen anymore., How will I combine the block_users table?

```
$GetPost = "SELECT Post.* FROM Post 
INNER JOIN Members ON Post.Poster_user_id = Members.User_id 
WHERE Status='active'";
```

Comment: Solved my problem from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623429/how-do-i-create-a-blocking-system-with-mysql-database

Comment: Do I have a schema of block_users table.

Answer (score 0):

you might try FULL OUTER JOIN 
the idea it to get all items in both tables member and block_users and then filter the data using where clause, i am sorry if i miss using the fields name , so please check the tables names, i assume  block_users.block_by_userid contained the blocked user id if not use the correct field

```
$GetPost = "SELECT Post.* FROM Post 
INNER JOIN Members ON Post.Poster_user_id = Members.User_id 
FULL OUTER JOIN block_users ON  Members.User_id  = block_users.user_id
WHERE Status='active' 
AND
WHERE block_users.block_by_userid != Members.User_id";
```

Comment: how could you JOIN  block_users table On members if the main query is from post? this create error.

Comment: I assume members has many posts and members has one buckled user. Member. User_ID is pk and blocked_user.user_id is fk

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I am doing this for a user xyz whose user_id is 123 then below is a query which will return expected output for user 123.

Query:

```
SELECT Post.* FROM Post 
INNER JOIN Members ON Post.Poster_user_id = Members.User_id 
WHERE Status='active' and post.poster_user_id NOT IN(select block_by_userid from block_users where blocked_user_id = 123 UNION select blocked_user_id from block_users where block_by_userid = 123)
```